# Apache software documentation in PDF format

Tags: apache, pdf, documentation

I'm looking for documentation for various Apache software in PDF format, so I can read them offline, on my ebook reader, for example. I'm looking especially for the user guides for Velocity and CXF. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used an online PDF converter. The result is not perfect, but it's readable...

Answer (score 1):

If your ebook reader has a web browser, you could create a local mirror in html and use that when a PDF version is not available. You can use the GPL tool wget for that:

> wget -mk -np
>   http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html

wget will preserve all links in a consistent manner.